# Add foreign key to a migration (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I´ve spent the whole day trying to figure out what is happening with the following migration.

This the migration of the table. My idea is  to use 'id_stays_abroad' and 'user_id' as foreign keys.

```
    class CreateBookingStaysAbroad extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('booking__stays__abroads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_stays_abroad')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->date('departure_date');
            $table->date('return_date');
            $table->integer('number_weeks');

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('booking__stays__abroad');
    }
}
```

This is the other migration to add the foreign keys

```
   class AddForeignKeyBookingStaysAbroadTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('booking__stays__abroads', function($table) {

            $table->foreign('id_stays_abroad')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('stays_abroads');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
            Schema::table('booking__stays__abroads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('booking__stays__abroads_id_stays_abroad_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('booking__stays__abroads_user_id_foreign');

    });
  }
}
```

When I run php artisan migrate I got the following error:

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `booking__stays__abroads` add constraint `booking__stays__abroads_id_stays_abroad_foreign` foreign key (`id_stays_abroad`) references `stays_abroads` (`id`))

Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: Are the 2 columns in question the same type and length? Does the table `id_stays_abroad` exist ?

Comment: Can you show your `stays_abroads` migration?

Comment: Try `$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_stays_abroad')->nullable();` and `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();` instead, I don't think `unsignedInteger` and `bigIncrements` are the same datatype in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the same column definition for `id` and `id_stays_abroad`. Use `unsignedBigInteger` instead of `unsignedInteger`.

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_stays_abroad')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
```

Comment: General error: 1825 Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'booking__stays__abroads'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'hr@002denglish/booking__stays__abroads_user_id_foreign'")  I´ve got this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NoelIñiguez You have to update both foreign keys. Not only one. Have a look at my update.

Comment: You were right. Thank you so much. I really apreciate it.

Comment: @NoelIñiguez No problem, you can accept my answer on the left. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this make this i think your id in users table is bigIncrements.so for foreignkey use this

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_stays_abroad')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
```

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
Schema::table('booking__stays__abroads', function($table) {

            $table->foreign('id_stays_abroad')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('stays_abroads');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users');
        });
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
Schema::table('booking__stays__abroads', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('booking__stays__abroads_id_stays_abroad_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('booking__stays__abroads_user_id_foreign');

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunetly I´ve got this error: PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1825 Failed to add the foreign key constraint on table 'booking__stays__abroads'. Incorrect options in FOREIGN KEY constraint 'hr@002denglish/booking__stays__abroads_id_stays_abroad_foreign'")

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the attribute should be named `stays_abroad_id` and not `id_stays_abroad`.

The issue is that the size and nature of `stays_abroads.id` and `stays_abroid_id` should match (unsigned big integer in this case).

Also, you dont need an ID in a pivot table. You will not be declaring a model for it in laravel.

The name of the table should reflect the two sides of the pivot table, so name it `stays_abroad_user` (singular and alphabetic order separated by an underscore)

```php
class CreateBookingStaysAbroad extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stays_abroad_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('stays_abroad_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->date('departure_date');
            $table->date('return_date');
            $table->integer('number_weeks');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('stays_abroad_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('stays_abroads');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stays_abroad_user');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite new to Laravel but I think you might need to change these two data types:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('id_stays_abroad')->nullable();
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
```

to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('id_stays_abroad')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
```

Worth a try!